# Angular and Mixins: unable to make it work in Ivy

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-injector, typescript-mixins

## Introduction

Hi Everybody,
I'm struggling with a difficult use case of **mixin in Typescript with Angular**. (not mixin in SCSS)
I'd like to use *mixins to create complex custom form inputs.*

### Problem

In the example, we have the **TextComponent** for the basic implementation of our mixins:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wva4z7?embed=1&file=src/app/inputs/text.component.ts

as you can see, I use 3 mixins in the extends:

- **CvaConnectorMixin**: ControlValueAccessor logic with some basic inputs
- **LengthValidatorMixin**: To add inputs concerning the minLength and maxLength for the input
- **ErrorStateMatcherMixin**: To manage custom ErrorStateMatcher in our input

At the end, we have the **Base** which is the base class containing the Injector and all ready to use lifecycle of Angular:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wva4z7?file=src/app/mixins/base-class-injector.ts

It means, in every mixin I use, I should have access to my Injector and all inputs/outputs/properties written in each of my mixin inside my TextComponent.

In Development environment, it works, but once I go in production, I get the error:
⚠️ `NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context`

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

This issue is also referenced here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found!

### TL;DR

Replace each @Injectable() in each mixin by @Directive.

### Explanation

With Ivy, @Injectable() is becoming mandatory to use DI inside our classes, however when the lib/app is built, it removes the decorator. Which is not the case for @Directive.